# ARM vs X86 : How to make a choice?

Tags: embedded, cpu-architecture

I have recently seen 32 bit ARM processors. I wonder why we can't construct a desktop computer using it. In that case how it differ from X86 ? Do the ARM architecture consume less power ..is it the reason of using them in embedded systems ?

- Why do we have two (ARM and X86) processor architectures ?
- Why do we generally use ARM architecture for embedded and x86 for workstations ?
- What is a general criteria for selecting one over the other.

Comment: ARM is not a very recent thing. It's been there for years. x86 processor dominates the market because a lot of desktop software is written for it and Intel has invested heavily to improve its performance. ISA-wise, ARM is really superior to x86.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have evidently led a very sheltered life - there are many more processor architectures than just x86 and ARM.

ARM has very good performance per watt, so is particularly suited to mobile/embedded systems.

There have been desktop systems with ARM CPUs in the past - look up Acorn Archimedes. Unfortunately the lowest common denominator (i.e. Microsoft) currently prevails in the operating system (and therefore application) market-place, but that will not always be the case.

Comment: "that will not always be the case" - [citation needed]

Comment: I'd say it's a good bet that things will change.  Google is likely to be pushing an ARM-based netbook set up to run Google Apps using Chrome OS in the near future.  That and the iPad are likely to change the game at the low end (although the iPad will have a custom Apple processor).  Besides, things always change in this business.

Comment: ARM based architectures run millions of embedded systems around the world, and ARM based cpu architectures are at the heart of most of the world's smart-phones, PDAs and network appliances.

Comment: @David Thornley/DrJokepu: If ARM did take off on the "desktop", you can bet Microsoft would implement an ARM version. Remember, Windows NT originally came in three processor architectures: x86, MIPS, and DEC Alpha. It'll happen again if it needs to...

Comment: @Mark:  I've heard rumors that Microsoft has a policy of maintaining a non-x64/x64 version of Windows, just to make sure it never is locked into a CPU architecture.  They may have a functioning ARM version as I write this, for all I know.  Almost certainly they could have one up and running reasonably soon.

Comment: @David Thornley: Microsoft has been running Windows Mobile on ARM for a very long time, so it's a simple fact that they have extensive experience with the platform...